# One bus for multiple pipelines - is it possible?

Tags: gstreamer

Is it possible to link N pipelines to one bus?

I have N "source pipelines" and one "sink pipeline", every time one source-pipeline finishes to transmit file to the sink-pipeline, the next pipeline needs to transmit other file also to that sink-pipeline,  by setting its state to "playing".

So my question is how to manage the bus to handle N pipelines, is it possible?
if not, is there one entity that could do that?

The code is written in c++,  gstreamer 1.0

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can have several distinct bins in one pipeline. Then those share the bus.